# How reduce the dimention of sparse vectros in python?

Tags: python, vector

Based on some calculations i have made dictionary of lists (or vectors) such as:

```
and': array([0., 0., 2., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        2., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 6., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]),
 'come': array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]),
 'back': array([1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.]),
 'home': array([0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]),
```

As it can be seen lists contain a lot of zeros which will mislead the calculation of similarity. How can i reduce the number of zeros (dimensions) or how can i reduce the sparseness of the vectors?

Comment: Are you opposed to simply using [`scipy.sparse`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html) or do you want to roll your own? Otherwise there are at least a half dozen sparse storage schemes, if you read up on those scipy docs you'll see some of the available options you can implement

Comment: @CoryKramer  i didn't know this. does it reduce the dimension of vectors?

Comment: They are basically a variety of data structures that try their best to only store non-zero values. The way they do that is implementation specific based on the underlying data structure.

Comment: @CoryKramer  i want to compute similarity of vectors based on these vectors. but having too much zeros wastes time and misleads similarity calculation

Comment: i dont mean to store a sparse matrix. i want to reduce dimension. i mean reduce them in a meaningful way